# How can I insert multiple data in excel file mybe using a for loop in java

Tags: java

I need to insert multiple data in an excel file at once, I was think a for loop will do but struggling to get the code

[image]

I have attached the sample outcome I am looking for. below is also a code I have tried but only inserting one value

```
public static void createExcelDataObjects(String filename) {

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("data");

    //This data needs to be written (Object[])
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<>();
    data.put("0", new Object[]{"number", "idNo", "idType", "personType"});


    data.put("1", new Object[]{1234, GenerateApplicantData.getIdNumber(), "I", "N",});


    //Iterate over data and write to sheet
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
        }
    }


    try {
        //Write the workbook in file system
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        log.info("Files Successfully Created.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @RalfRenz the prople it doesnt add multiple data for example on the name columns i want to have alot of names going down